# client/main.less file not being loaded by Meteor 1.3

Tags: meteor, less, meteor-blaze

I have a Meteor 1.3 and my `client/main.less` file is not being imported. My expectation is this should be happening by default. I have the `less` Meteor package installed.

Interesting enough, `client/main.scss` IS being imported. Why would that happen if I have the `less` package installed?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's not being loaded? Good way to check is to put some errors in there to see if it fails.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and the compiler didn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the file isn't being loaded for some reason. Perhaps there is an error in the file that prevents inclusion, but is somehow not reported.

Try replacing it with a small file with a very noticeable result (like changing the page background colour to something bright)

Comment: Interesting enough, `client/main.scss` IS being imported. Why would that happen if I have the less package installed?

Comment: that is strange, because SCSS files are not supported, you need the fourseven:scss package for that